# Swift 4 Alamofire upload file with parameters to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, swift, asp.net-mvc, alamofire

I have an ASP.NET MVC Controller defined like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public string uploadQAImage(FileUploadClass fileUploadClass, HttpPostedFile image)
{
}
```

And this what the class FileUploadClass looks like.

```
public class FileUploadClass
{
    public string job { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public string itemId { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do with Alamofire in iOS is call this Controller, I have tried using parameters:

```
func saveQAPhotos(_ cellHolder: PhotoClass, completion: @escaping (_ result: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)
    {

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "job" : cellHolder.job!,
            "itemId" : cellHolder.itemId!,
            "createdBy" : appDelegate.username!
        ]

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "uploadQAImage");

        urlComponents?.user = appDelegate.username;

        urlComponents?.password = appDelegate.password;

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
            }

            if let data = cellHolder.photo {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

        }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url!, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in


                    if let result = response.result.value {

                        let jsonData = result as! Dictionary<String, Any>

                        completion(jsonData)

                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                print("error")

            }

        }

    }
```

But that didn't work on the ASP.NET side I get this error:

> can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content

I have also tried sending the data as `[AnyHashable: Any]` like so:

```
func saveQAPhotos(_ cellHolder: PhotoClass, completion: @escaping (_ result: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Void)
    {

        var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        jsonDict["job"] = cellHolder.job

        jsonDict["itemId"] = cellHolder.itemId

        jsonDict["createdBy"] = appDelegate.username

        let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "uploadQAImage");

        urlComponents?.user = appDelegate.username;

        urlComponents?.password = appDelegate.password;

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append(jsonData!, withName: "fileUploadClass", mimeType: "application/json")

            if let data = cellHolder.photo {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

        }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url!, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in


                    if let result = response.result.value {

                        let jsonData = result as! Dictionary<String, Any>

                        completion(jsonData)

                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                print("error")

            }

        }

    }
```

Same error as before

> can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content

Now when I change the ASP.NET Controller to only get FileUploadClass like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public string uploadQAImage(FileUploadClass fileUploadClass)
{
}
```

I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can only assume if I do fix the can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content error I will get this error next.

I am pretty sure I am sending the data incorrectly, so I guess my question is how do I send data from Alamofire upload method to an ASP.NET MVC method?